# setting my main project default to linear instead of relative

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

Everytime I follow a tutorial book or you tube video, I have also used the cheat help in eclipse. My programming always comes out with errors. here is one example why does all the tutorials main activity comes out showing linear layout and my projects default is relative layout. So how do I change the default to linear when creating new project.

I know I can open a new layout xml but all the tutorials opens a new project in linear.
I am a massive fan of android and I really want to make some apps, but all the tutorials never seem to correspond with the results I get and they all make it look so easy.

Comment: errrr.... instead of changing the default behaviour of ADT, why not simply change the root layout to `LinearLayout` right after creating a project?

Comment: Check my answer for Android studio @ppx100

Answer (score 0):

- go to youre layout.xml
- make sure to be in the graphical layout (check bottom bar)
- top-right in 'outline' right-click on the relative layout
- choose 'change layout'
- choose youre desired layout, (linearlayout(vertical) probably in ur case)

Answer (score 0):

I found it after digging a lot in **Android Studio** After visiting JetBrains and Intelij documentation and help sections i found nothing much helpful but i found way on my own, I had answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38160861/5476209), With all explanation and screenshots.