# create linear layout in android by default when making new app instead of relative

Tags: android, android-layout

why when i create new application in android it made with relative layout instead of linear layout....
how can i create linear layout when i create new app by default instead of relative ?

```
enter code here
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Comment: eclipse and jdk-8u25-windows-x64

Comment: why every time run application this message appear ??
[2015-01-30 22:39:15 - example1] Failed to install example1.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
[2015-01-30 22:39:15 - example1] Launch canceled!

Answer (score 0):

Ok Follow this steps and you can do it but i am 99% sure only.

**Go to res-> layout folder** and Right Click on it and you get a sidebar asking for what type of file you want to create
Go to -> **Edit File Templates** option. 

Sidebar>
[image: Sidebar]

You will see this dialog opened. 
You see both options right there inside **Other tab** These options are **LayoutResourceFile.xml** and **LayoutResourceFile_vertical.xml** 
[image: Dialog where you have to make change]

Change the **${ROOT_TAG}**  to LinearLayout in both of these **LayoutResourceFile.xml** and **LayoutResourceFile_vertical.xml** and you will always get LinearLayout as parent for future.

[image]